# Owl Carousel 2 resize window bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I decided to make a slider on Owl Carousel 2. Everything works fine, I like it, but I've noticed a bug. When I change the size of the browser window (only Chrome), the slider items are rearranged and there is a phantom item on back side.

HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x240?text=Slide%200">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x240?text=Slide%201">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x240?text=Slide%202">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x240?text=Slide%203">
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 20,
    items: 3,
    nav: true,
});
```

Screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix it?

[[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvBrQJ)]

Comment: seems like a rendering bug, i don't have this bug (tried FF / Chrome / IE11 / Edge 12)

Comment: @Dustin, Probably yes, I see it only in Chrome and when I reload the page it disappears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I am glad i could help :)

Comment: Thank you ! Should be integrated in Owl Carousel 2 !

Comment: Dear lord!  Thank you very much for posting this.  It actually solved another, slightly different Owl Carousel 2 problem I was having...